# Xcode build script to separate image channels?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to figure out how to split JPEG with 4 channels(r,g,b,a) on two images - one should be JPEG with RGB information, other is PNG with only alpha channel in it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Also, please put more effort into your question and only apply appropriate tags.)

Comment: Emmm.. not sure what to add to the question. I have jpg with 4 channels and want to split it onto 2 files during build phase. So to avoid to save 2 files in photoshop but just to cut alpha channel from jpgs via xcode script. I will have about 100 similar files with color information and alpha channel(b/w). I want to reduce app's size to avoid saving large pngs with transparency in it. Similar to the script that creates png and @2x.png from psd during build.

Comment: `JPEG` images cannot contain alpha channels so you do not have a `JPEG` with (r,g,b,a).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is download the ImageMagik package. It has a huge number of command line programs that you can use in scripts to do "magic" with images.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome) a open source library for image manipulation:

```
// NOTE you SHOULD cvReleaseImage() for the return value when end of the code.
- (IplImage *)CreateIplImageFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    IplImage *iplimage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image.size.width, image.size.height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(iplimage->imageData, iplimage->width, iplimage->height,
                                                    iplimage->depth, iplimage->widthStep,
                                                    colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    IplImage *ret = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(iplimage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvCvtColor(iplimage, ret, CV_RGBA2BGR);
    cvReleaseImage(&iplimage);

    return ret;
}

//detecting blobs and drawing countours arround it
- (void) splitImage : (UIImage *) image {
    if(!image)
        return;

    IplImage *iplImageFromImage = [self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:image];
    cvSetImageROI(iplImageFromImage, cvRect(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height));

    //splitting image detecting blob and then mergin it back

     cout <<"channels = "<<iplImageFromImage->nChannels<<"\n";
     IplImage *hImage, *sImage, *vImage, *fImage;
     cvSplit(iplImageFromImage, &hImage, &sImage, &vImage, &fImage);

     CvMat tmp; CvMat* mat = cvGetMat(iplImageFromImage, &tmp, 0, 0);
     CvMat *hImage_m = cvCreateMat(mat->rows, mat->cols, CV_8UC1),
     *sImage_m = cvCreateMat(mat->rows, mat->cols, CV_8UC1),
     *vImage_m = cvCreateMat(mat->rows, mat->cols, CV_8UC1);
     cvSplit(mat, hImage_m, sImage_m, vImage_m, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks rptwsthi. But that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something scriptable?
[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) package has convert utility which can extract image channels:

```
  convert rose: -channel R -separate separate_red.gif
  convert rose: -channel G -separate separate_green.gif
  convert rose: -channel B -separate separate_blue.gif
```

Read [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#separate) about Separating Channel Images.

Imagemagick works just fine on OSX.